# Making / keeping the site expert friendly

Tags: discussion

I'm a novice at this subject. There are many questions I could ask that are pretty basic. These sorts of questions may have some benefit to future readers, since getting a critical mass of knowledge in this area is tricky.

My concern, though, is that too many basic questions will lower the signal-to-noise question ratio for experts and make the site less interesting.

My question is severalfold:

1. Is this a real concern?
2. Is this worth considering now?
3. What can we do about it collectively?
4. What should users without a strong background in the subject matter do as individuals?

Comment: In short this is why the private beta exist. Your questions are not getting down votes and closed or warnings in comments so take that as *The community is fine with your questions, don't stop*. The concerns some of us have have are evident by questions that are closed and have large numbers of down votes. As users gain more privileges then these questions will get closed faster and deleted.

Comment: Remember that no one is required to be here and that not all of the experts are actively looking at each question much less even on this site or care to ever be here. I would also not be surprised if some put their toe in the water and will never be back.

Comment: @GuyCoder This is kind of orthogonal to my original concern, but I've been avoiding accepting answers yet because the site is still very new. I'll go through and accept some.